# Undefined variable when passing dictionary to a submodule-role

Tags: ansible

I'm having a really weird problem on my ansible role. I send two dictionaries to a submodule like that:

```
import_role:
  name: .submodules/monitoring-plugins
vars:
  monitoring_plugins:
    check_content:
      command: "files/icinga/commands/check_content"
      dest: "{{ icinga_server_plugin_directory }}"
      group: "root"
      owner: "root"
      mode: "0755"
      package: "curl"
      src: "files/plugins/server/check_content"
    check_http_response_time:
      command: "files/icinga/commands/check_http_response_time"
      dest: "{{ icinga_server_plugin_directory }}"
      group: "root"
      owner: "root"
      mode: "0775"
      src: "files/plugins/server/check_http_response_time"
    check_https_response_time:
      command: "files/icinga/commands/check_https_response_time"
      dest: "{{ icinga_server_plugin_directory }}"
      group: "root"
      owner: "root"
      mode: "0775"
      src: "files/plugins/server/check_https_response_time"
    check_port:
      command: "files/icinga/commands/check_port"
      dest: "{{ icinga_server_plugin_directory }}"
      group: "root"
      owner: "root"
      mode: "0775"
      src: "files/plugins/server/check_port"
    check_ssl_cert:
      command: "files/icinga/commands/check_ssl_cert"
      dest: "{{ icinga_server_plugin_directory }}"
      group: "root"
      owner: "root"
      mode: "0775"
      src: "files/plugins/server/check_ssl_cert"
  custom_services:
    content:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "content"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/content.conf') }}"
    http_response_time:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "http_response_time"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/http_response_time.conf') }}"
    https_response_time:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "https-response-time"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/https_response_time.conf') }}"
    http_port:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "http-port"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/http_port.conf') }}"
    https_port:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "https-port"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/https_port.conf') }}"
    ssl_cert:
      service-preamble: 'apply Service "ssl-cert"'
      configuration: |
        {{ common_service_header }}
        assign where host.vars.ansible.system == "Linux"
      definition:
        "{{ lookup('template', 'config/services/ssl_cert.conf') }}"
```

on the submodule I created two debug tasks:

```
- debug:
    var: monitoring_plugins
- debug:
    var: custom_services
```

output:

```
    ok: [server.test] => {
    "monitoring_plugins": {
        "check_content": {
            "command": "files/icinga/commands/check_content",
            "dest": "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins",
            "group": "root",
            "mode": "0755",
            "owner": "root",
            "package": "curl",
            "src": "files/plugins/server/check_content"
        },
        "check_http_response_time": {
            "command": "files/icinga/commands/check_http_response_time",
            "dest": "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins",
            "group": "root",
            "mode": "0775",
            "owner": "root",
            "src": "files/plugins/server/check_http_response_time"
        },
        "check_https_response_time": {
            "command": "files/icinga/commands/check_https_response_time",
            "dest": "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins",
            "group": "root",
            "mode": "0775",
            "owner": "root",
            "src": "files/plugins/server/check_https_response_time"
        },
        "check_port": {
            "command": "files/icinga/commands/check_port",
            "dest": "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins",
            "group": "root",
            "mode": "0775",
            "owner": "root",
            "src": "files/plugins/server/check_port"
        },
        "check_ssl_cert": {
            "command": "files/icinga/commands/check_ssl_cert",
            "dest": "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins",
            "group": "root",
            "mode": "0775",
            "owner": "root",
            "src": "files/plugins/server/check_ssl_cert"
        }
    }
}

TASK [.submodules/monitoring-plugins : debug] ************************************
ok: [server.test] => {
    "custom_services": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Does anybody have any idea what could possibly go wrong? I sent both of them from the very same task but yet one of them looks just fine and the other don't. I even tried to remove the submodule and add it again but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: You may want to change your test to `- debug: var=hostvars` and see what is actually available, but that's a weird one for sure

Comment: @mdaniel I also thought it was weird until I tried. But a var definition containing other vars expansions which are undefined is undefined. So it actually make sense (IMO...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The background

A var containing other vars expansion being undefined cannot be interpreted and is undefined.

```sh
$ ansible localhost -e undef="{{ i_dont_exist }}" -m debug -a var=undef
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "undef": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

To see what is going wrong, you need to actually expand the var at debug time

```sh
$ ansible localhost -e undef="{{ i_dont_exist }}" -m debug -a msg="{{ undef }}"
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'i_dont_exist' is undefined"
}
```

## Your specific case

The root cause is that `common_service_header` is undefined. Since it is used inside your variable definition for the role include, ansible tries to interpret it, fails, and the var stays undefined.

You will actually see the same result for `monitoring_plugins` if you undefine `icinga_server_plugin_directory`.

To have some more info on what actually happens, the "trick" is to force ansible to interpret the variable in your debug. There are two possible ways to do this:

```yaml
- name: Use a simple jinja2 expansion
  debug:
    msg: "{{ custom_services }}"

- name: Use a the 'vars' lookup
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'custom_services') }}"
```

Which then gives a more meaningful info (reformated for legibility....):

```
TASK [.submodules/monitoring-plugins : debug] *****************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an
undefined variable. The error was: 'common_service_header' is undefined\n\n
The error appears to be in 
'/some/path/.submodules/monitoring-plugins/tasks/main.yml': line 4, column 3, 
but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n
The offending line appears to be:\n\n    
msg: \"{{ lookup('vars', 'monitoring_plugins') }}\"\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! common_serivce_header is actually defined (I omitted it here because I thought it's irrelevant) but it is actually the reason why it fails. So I guess that variable-inside-Jinja-block approach doesn't work that way. I at least know what happened, so I'll keep debugging it from here.

Comment: Sorry, first time here for me. That comment was sent too early, I edited it but you were quicker than me :)

Comment: I actually deleted my comment when I saw your comment edit ;) Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks :) I had a great first experience thanks to you!